# Apache suddenly not working

Tags: apache2, hibernate

My apache on xubuntu 16.04 is not working after waking up from hibernation. Reboot didnt help. When I try to restart I get the following message:

> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl
>   -xe" for details.

trying `systemctl status apache2.service` returns

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sa 2016-08-20 21:24:49 CEST; 6min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6005 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 20 21:24:49 johndoe apache2[6005]: Output of config test was:
Aug 20 21:24:49 johndoe apache2[6005]: [Sat Aug 20 21:24:49.248413 2016] [core:crit] [pid 6015] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00077: alloc_listener: failed to set up sockaddr for localhost
Aug 20 21:24:49 johndoe apache2[6005]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 5 of /etc/apache2/ports.conf:
Aug 20 21:24:49 johndoe apache2[6005]: Listen setup failed
Aug 20 21:24:49 johndoe apache2[6005]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Aug 20 21:24:49 johndoe apache2[6005]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Aug 20 21:24:49 johndoe systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 20 21:24:49 johndoe systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Aug 20 21:24:49 johndoe systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 20 21:24:49 johndoe systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The mentioned `ports.conf` looks fine (line 5 is Listen localhost:80):

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen localhost:80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And there is nothing to find in the `error.log`

Comment: @user577728  could you please post your  ` /etc/hosts ` and `  sudo netstat -tplan | grep apache2 `    report .

Answer (score 1):

The connection between domain names (such as localhost) and IP addresses (such as 127.0.0.1) is made in `/etc/hosts` (or in your local DNS server). I think the configuration error is that you can't make Apache listen on a domain name (e.g. localhost), but you must use an IP address.

To make Apache listen on a domain name, you have to configure a `VirtualHost` (see [the apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) for an explanation).

Answer (score 0):

ok it was actually the

```
Listen localhost:80
```

it must be changed to

```
Listen 80
```

I remember, that I once changed it to localhost:80 to restrict the connection from outside. Maybe its not workng any longer because of an recent update? I have Apache/2.4.18

problem is, that I cant use localhost as url now, I have to call 127.0.0.1

Comment: can the problem be the result of an apache update?